# How to parse complex date/time string into zoo object?

Tags: r, zoo

I'm trying to convert the following date/time string into a zoo object:

2004:071:15:23:41.87250

2004:103:15:24:15.35931

year:doy:hour:minute:second

The date/time string is stored in a dataframe without headers. What's the best way to go about this in R?

Cheers!

Edit based on answer by Gavin:

```
# read in time series from CSV file; each entry as described above
timeSeriesDates <- read.csv("timeseriesdates.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
# convert to format that can be used as a zoo object
timeSeriesDatesZ <- as.POSIXct(timeSeriesDates$V1, format = "%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read the data in to R in the usual way. You will have something like the following:

```
dats <- data.frame(times = c("2004:071:15:23:41.87250", "2004:103:15:24:15.35931"))
dats
```

These can be converted to one of the `POSIXt` classes via:

```
dats <- transform(dats, as.POSIXct(times, format = "%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S"))
```

or

```
data$times <- as.POSIXct(dats$times, format = "%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S"))
```

which can then be used in a zoo object. See `?strftime` for details on the placeholders used in the `format` argument; essentially `%j` is the day of the year placeholder.

To do the **zoo** bit, we would do, using some dummy data for the actual time series

```
ts <- rnorm(2) ## dummy data
require(zoo)   ## load zoo
tsZoo <- zoo(ts, dats$times)
```

the last line gives:

```
> tsZoo
2004:071:15:23:41.87250 2004:103:15:24:15.35931 
              0.3503648              -0.2336064
```

One thing to note with fractional seconds is that i) the exact fraction you have may not be recordable using floating point arithmetic. Also, R may not show the full fractional seconds given the value of an option in R; `digits.secs`. See `?options` for more on this particular option and how to change it.

Comment: I read in the csv file like so:

timeSeriesDates <- read.csv("timeseriesdates.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
timeSeriesDatesZ <- as.POSIXct(timeSeriesDates, format = "%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S")

Returned the following:

Error in as.POSIXct.default(timeSeriesDates, format = "%Y:%j:%H:%M:%S") : 
  do not know how to convert 'timeSeriesDates' to class "POSIXct"

Comment: @Prophet60091 Yes, sorry; changed my Answer after re-reading your Q and noted the point about reading the data in. See my edit. `timeSeriesDates` is a data frame with at least one column. That column is your times. You need to refer to that column by name. I use `dats$times` you need to use `timeSeriesDates$foo` where `foo` is the name of the variable. I presume `X1` but what does `names(timeSeriesDates)` say? Use what it says in place of `foo`.

Comment: Thx Gavin! The edits worked. I will clarify the question above.

Comment: @Prophet60091 I have also made some further edits which may explain a few more bits of how to achieve what you are wanting to do and what my code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a commented example for the first string:

```
R> s <- "2004:103:15:24:15.35931"
R> # split on the ":" and convert the result to a numeric vector
R> n <- as.numeric(strsplit(s, ":")[[1]])
R> # Use the year, hour, minute, second to create a POSIXct object
R> # for the first of the year; then add the number of days (as seconds)
R> ISOdatetime(n[1], 1, 1, n[3], n[4], n[5])+n[2]*60*60*24
[1] "2004-04-13 16:24:15 CDT"
```